# How to save time along with AM/PM in yii2

Tags: php, sql, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a field named departure_time in my table.
When I am trying to save the time it shows `"Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect time value: '11:15 AM'` for column `'departure_time' at row 1"` error.

The data type for `departure_time` in my table is `TIME`.I am using kartiks time picker. Help me to find this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically Time data_type format store only time value in databse.Also it takes only 24 hours format not am or pm format. If you want store value Thier are two solution .

> In data base , The data_type of field should be varchar. it will be store your value as you want.

Or

> You have to change your deprature_time in 24 hour format and store in database when you want to fetch it then use php date("h:i a") format on field. It will return your time value AM/PM format

Comment: @Dijo if you get your answer .. Then you should upvote or correct tick the answer. It may be useful for other StackOverflow visitors.